# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when trying to copy array C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When i run the following Segmentation Fault... The goal is to copy the argv array to allowdip array.

```
char *allowdip;
int *allowdipcount;


int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
  int xer;

  allowdipcount = argc;

  for(xer=0; xer<allowdipcount; xer++) {
    allowdip[xer]=argv[xer];
  }

  for(xir=0; xir<allowdipcount -1; xir++) {
    printf("%s\n", allowdip[xir]);
  }


exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks, now my code is:

```
char **allowdip;
int allowdipcount;

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
  int xer;
  int xir;

  allowdipcount = argc;
  char **allowdip = malloc(allowdipcount * sizeof(char*));
  for(xer=0; xer<argc; xer++) {
      allowdip[xer]=argv[xer];
  }

    for(xir=1; xir<allowdipcount; xir++)
    printf("%s\n", allowdip[xir]);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

it returns:

```
 testscript2.c:51: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

the line 51 contains:

```
 allowdip[xer]=argv[xer];
```

Comment: `int *allowdipcount;` ->`int allowdipcount;` and `aloowip` not initialize

Comment: To start with, get a decent compiler.  Then, pay heed to the diagnostics it generates for the code you posted.

Comment: `char *argv` -- That's crap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`allowdip` is an uninitialised pointer.  You need to allocate memory for it

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int xer;
  int allowdipcount = argc;
  char **allowdip = malloc(allowdipcount * sizeof(char*));

  for(xer=0; xer<allowdipcount; xer++) {
      allowdip[xer]=argv[xer];
  }

  for(xer=0; xer<allowdipcount; xer++) {
    printf("%s\n", allowdip[xer]);
  }
  free(allowdip);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that I've made a few other changes in your code

- `allowdipcount` should be of type `int` (otherwise you need to allocate storage for it too)
- `allowdip` has changed type to be an array of `char` pointers
- the signature of `main` wasn't quite right - `argv` should be a `char*` array
- Changed your global variables to be local to `main` since there wasn't an obvious need for them to be global
- Changed the `printf` loop to iterate over all program arguments.  It was skipping the final arg in your question.
- freed the memory we allocated for `allowdip` once we're finished with it
- Simplified return from `main` as suggested by Vincent

Comment: JFYI, `allowdipcount` has a type `int *`.

Comment: @AlokSave You just beat me to it.  Ipdated answer includes code showing that `allowdipcount` should just be `int`

Comment: can we have second argument `char*` in main ? I believe that is also wrong.

Comment: Also using exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) instead of return EXIT_SUCCESS is not  useful in this case.

Comment: thanks this worked, but now this happends, i updated my question, i changed %d to %s by the way...

Comment: @Marco Your latest warning is caused by the signature for `main` being wrong.  Try using `char* argv[]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating memory, and your types are all wrong.

The counter should be an integer, not a pointer:

```
int allowdipcount;
```

and the array should be an array of pointers, not of characters:

```
char **allowdip;
```

Then you can allocate:

```
allowdip = malloc(argc * sizeof *allowdip);
```

and copy the array:

```
memcpy(allowdip, argv, argc * sizeof *allowdip);
```

Note that this doesn't copy the actual argument strings, only the array of pointers to strings. It also doesn't include the `NULL` pointer at `argv[argc]` which terminates the array.